# Trying to Configure Ring in Cassandra from datastax tutorial

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am trying to follow Datastax Cassandra self paced tutorial on Ring configuration. I followed the tutorial and prepared two nodes as suggested in the virtual machine but second node is not able to gossip.

I verified listener_address,RPC_address,seed but not able to configure the ring. Below is the exception I am receiving.

I am also attaching Cassandra Yaml files

**Node2:**

Cassandra YAML:  https://bitbucket.org/snippets/sreevastav/dL99d

Cassandra-env :  https://bitbucket.org/snippets/sreevastav/on88p

Exception received:

```
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any seeds
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1354)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:553)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:807)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:724)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:610)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:333)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:679)
ERROR 22:03:15 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1354) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:553) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:807) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:724) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:610) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:333) [apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551) [apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:679) [apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change Node2 `seeds` address, So that it match with `listen_address`**

```
# Compression to apply to the commit log. If omitted, the commit log
# will be written uncompressed.  LZ4, Snappy, and Deflate compressors
# are supported.
#commitlog_compression:
#   - class_name: LZ4Compressor
#     parameters:
#         -

# any class that implements the SeedProvider interface and has a
# constructor that takes a Map<String, String> of parameters will do.
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "127.0.0.2,127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Thank you Islam for responding. My Seed node is on 127.0.0.1 (node1). If I give Seed as 127.0.0.2, Cassandra will start with out error but it won't form Ring or gossip to share any details.I am sharing my node1 cassandra yaml file [Node1](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/sreevastav/Aryyj)

Comment: Then you should add both of their ip like `127.0.0.2,127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thank you Islam. Sorry for delay. It will start when I add 127.0.0.2 but did not form a ring.